# How to store into database on page Refresh with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if users are using the system.

I know have a last_login, with the standard laravel class UpdateLastLoggedInAt.

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
    $event->user->last_login = Carbon::now();
    $event->user->save();
}
```

This doesn't work if users let their browser window stay open.

Is there a way to have it so that on every page refresh or route change (users navigates through the website), change the last_login to that time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: either you can write a middleware which would log the time at every request. or you can user javascript to hit an url at a particular time interval which would log the time.

Comment: Yes i created a middleware, thanks man!

Comment: If you had already done that, what was the question about? :D

Comment: Nothing anymore! it's fixed now haha. Have a great day! @SayantanDas

Answer (score 0):

I created a middleware for this and wrapper it around all routes.

```
class LogLastSeen
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = User::find(Auth()->user()->id);
    $user->last_login = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    return $next($request);
}
```